# htaccess file causing an error with added MIME types

Tags: vb.net, .htaccess, webserver, mime-types

Hi I am adding a couple of MIME types to my htaccess file - below is a copy of what my htaccess file looks like.

AddType application/x-ms-application
AddType application/x-ms-manifest

I need to add these MIME types so I can launch my vb application from the web using visual studio clickonce deployment.

However when I add these to the htaccess file I get an internal server error

"Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

As soon as I remove the MIME types from the htaccess file, the page loads.. I am using hosting24.com as my web host.

Anyone know why this is happening ?

Thanks.

Comment: checked the server error log and this was there, /.htaccess: AddType requires at least two arguments, a mime type followed by one or more file extension, so I put a space next to eeach MIME type and then added there extensions .manifest and .application. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: Resolved - it was simply adding the extensions after each mime type. AddType application/x-ms-application .application
AddType application/x-ms-manifest .manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the server error log and got this message,

AddType requires at least two arguments, a mime type followed by one or more file extension

by adding the file extensions after each MIME type the page now loads.

AddType application/x-ms-application .application
AddType application/x-ms-manifest .manifest